# The separation symbol could not be found Unexpected data found. Trailing data

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

necesito recuperar de un request una fecha y guardar en la base solo el año.

Estoy haciendo lo siguiente

```
$fecha_actual=$request->get('dia');

Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fecha_actual);

$year = $fecha_actual->format('Y');

$turno->anio=$year;
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.
Gracias.

Comment: Realiza un `dd()` a `$request->get('dia');` y muestranos que obtienes como resultado

Comment: Obtengo lo siguiente "2021-03-05"

Comment: Y si ese es el formato, entonces por que tratas de usar como formato de origen este: `d/m/Y`

Comment: Igual me da error.

    $fecha_actual=$request->get('dia');

        Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $fecha_actual);
     
        $year = $fecha_actual->format('Y');

        $turno->anio=$year;
        
               $turno->save();


Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException
Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found.

Comment: Entonces para quedar claros, del request que recibes llega entre otra data la fecha en formato de *aaaa-mm-dd* y de eso quieres extraer únicamente el año y almacenarlo en la bd?

Comment: Además que tipo de dato es la columna donde planeas almacenarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comentarios:

1. Si del front te llega un *$request* donde entre otros datos te llega una fecha como la siguiente:

> "2021-03-05"

Entonces....

2. En el método `createFromFormat` no estás pasando el formato adecuado para la fecha que te llega en tu *request* y por eso el error que obtienes, entonces sería tan simple como esto:

   ```
   $fecha_actual = $request->get('dia');

   now()->createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $fecha_actual);

   $year = $fecha_actual->format('Y');
   ```

Lo que nos daría como salida:

> 2021

Ahora mas allá de que el resultado sería el esperado, te expongo lo siguiente:

- ¿Para qué intentar dar formato mediante los métodos de [*DateTime*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) a un valor que se almacenará de manera parcial?
- ¿Seguro que es conveniente que pierdas la fecha completa y solo almacenes el año?, ¿no eso te impediría tener registros con una marca de tiempo exacta?

Lo anterior te lo pregunto por que dado el resultado que buscas, entonces todos los pasos iniciales se vuelven nada necesarios y podemos solucionarlo así:

```
$fecha_actual = $request->get('dia');

explode("-", $fecha_actual)[0];   //2021
```

Donde con ayuda de [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) obtenemos el mismo resultado deseado.

**Referencia**

- [método `createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: La segunda opción funcionó perfecto. Muchas gracias.

Comment: donde debo marcarla, no me doy cuenta